# SharePoint 2013 IE 11 Document Mode Issue

Tags: 2013, master-page, custom-masterpage, ie, system-master-page

I am using SharePoint 2013 default Master Page seattle. We are also using K2 on our machines and it requires browsers to run on IE 9 or higher mode.

View source reveals that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta http-
equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-
equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" 
content="0" /><meta name="msapplication-TileImage" 
content="/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png" /><meta 
name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#0072C6" />
```

I checked the Document mode on F12, it is showing default as IE8 and renders on IE8. How do I force the pages to run on IE10. The same block of code runs fine on dev though. On Dev, I do get the IE10 document mode with same code.

Comment: The line `<meta http-
equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />` is the one used to force the pages to render in IE10 mode. Please verify you have published and approved the master after the change.

Comment: Hi Venkat, Thanks for the suggestion. The master page is published and is approved. It is the default master page and  meta tag is present in the master page.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestion. It was Enterprise mode that was forcing IE to load on IE8. Modifying the Policy we were able to revert it to IE10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Enterprise mode that was forcing IE to load on IE8. Modifying the Policy we were able to revert it to IE10.

Answer (score 2):

IE 10 screws Up lots of thing. I would either use Chrome or force with IE 11.

```
<meta http- equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```