# Site collection is not working in IE11 but works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a site, which was created using sharepoint online, that works fine on Chrome and Firefox but not working in IE11. It works fine once I change the document mode (in developer mode) to 11 instead of 10. Not sure how to make it work without changing the document mode as this is not a solution (Can't change this setting for the computers of anyone who visits the website).

Comment: I already tried all of them and nothing work except changing the document mode. The concole shows an error SCRIPT5009: 'Set' is undefined. require-951f856e.js (1,1662)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the site, but it sounds like you have customizations that are breaking the site. The fix is to get the developers who built the customizations to fix them.

Comment: You can set it up in master page adding <meta http- equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />. I have done it https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220838/sharepoint-2013-ie-11-document-mode-issue

Comment: I already tried that but it makes no difference

Comment: can you add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` to the `<head>` tag in master page and check ? Once done, checkin and publish the masterpage. By doing this, it will force the compatibility mode to edge(i.e latest) wherever available.

Comment: please share your console window screenshot

Comment: seems you have added some custom js code OR refer 3rd party .js file that does not support IE10. try to remove that code/js (by identifying in console), then try. and let us know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add some custom code in the site in SharePoint online?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Add the site into compatibility view in IE11.
2. Clear IE cache.
3. Reset IE settings. Go to IE->internet options->advanced tab->reset.
4. Switch to other computer to check if the same issue will occur.

There is a similar post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501116/react-set-is-undefined-on-sharepoint